# Spring - JWTParser(String) not found

Tags: java, oauth, spring-security, jwt

I have a token based authentication scheme in Spring. But the JWTParser seems troublesome. What does JWTParser class in the below code really do? Also, I cant import this class.

```
public class JWTAuthenticationToken extends AbstractAuthenticationToken {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final Object principal;
    private Object details;

    Collection authorities;

    public JWTAuthenticationToken( String jwtToken ) {
        super( null );
        super.setAuthenticated( true ); // must use super, as we override
        JWTParser parser = new JWTParser( jwtToken );

        this.principal = parser.getSub();

        this.setDetailsAuthorities();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPrincipal() {
        return principal;
    }

    private void setDetailsAuthorities() {
        String username = principal.toString();
        SpringUserDetailsAdapter adapter = new SpringUserDetailsAdapter( username );
        details = adapter;
        authorities = ( Collection ) adapter.getAuthorities();

    }

    @Override
    public Collection getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

Any work around?

Comment: I am having same issue please answer it if you got any workaround

Comment: @Ravi unfortunately I found no work around at all

Comment: Thanks for your response @Vishnu G S. I figured out a workaround.

Comment: @Ravi post it some one might benefit

Answer (score 1):

```
JwtParser parser =new  DefaultJwtParser();
parser.parse(jwtToken);

<dependency>
 <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
 <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
 <version>0.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: While code-only answers can be valid in simple contexts, please notice that they are unrecommended. Try to explain or contextualize the code by mentioning *what* the code does and *how* it does it.